# SQL structure vs. C++ STL map

Tags: c++, sql, database, dictionary, stl

I just finished a course in data structs and algorithms (cpp) in my school and I am interested in databasing in the real world... so specifically SQL.

So my question is what is the difference between SQL and for example c++ stl std::multimap? Is SQL faster? or can I make an equally as fast (time complexity wise) homemade SQL using a c++ STL?

thanks!
(sorry I'm new to programming outside the boundaries of my classes)

Comment: SQL is a query language, `std::multimap` is a container in the C++ Standard Library. They are two very different things. Might as well be asking for the differences between a sex doll and an encyclopedia.

Comment: Wait, so is it completely irrelevant to even compare between the two? And also, is it possible to implement a fully shippable SQL-like database purely using std::multimap?

Comment: Databases are specialized in what they do -- store data.  It isn't as simple as declaring a multimap.  What happens when your "multimap" database has to store millions of records?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Will multimap find millions of records faster than sql?

Answer (score 6):

The obvious difference is that [SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) is a *query language* to interact with database while [STL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library) is library (conventionally, STL is also used to refer to a certain subset of the [standard C++ library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Standard_Library)). As such, these are apples and oranges.

SQL actually entails a suite of standards specifying various parts of a database system. For a database system to be useful it is desirable that certain characteristics are met ([ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID). Even just looking at these there is no requirement that they are met by STL containers. I think only the *consistency* would even be desirable for STL container:

1. STL container mutations are not required to be *atomic*: when an exception is thrown from within one of the mutating functions the container may become unusable, i.e., STL containers are only required to meet the [basic exception guarantee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_safety).
2. As mentioned, [successful] mutations yield to a consistent state.
3. STL containers can't be currently mutated and read, i.e., there is no concept of *isolation*. If you want to access an STL container in a concurrent environment you need to make sure that there is no other accessor when the container is being mutated (you can have as many concurrent readers while there is not mutator, though).
4. There is on concept of *durability* for STL containers while it may be considered the core feature of databases to be durable (well, all ACID features can be considered core database features).

Database internally certainly use some data structures and algorithms to provide the ACID features. This is an area where STL may come in, although primarily with its key strength, i.e., *algorithms* which aren't really "[algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithm)" but rather "solvers for specific problems": STL is the foundation of an efficient algorithm library which is applicable to arbitrary data structures (well, that's the objective - [I don't think it is, yet, achieved](https://github.com/dietmarkuehl/kuhllib/wiki/STL-2.0)). Sadly, important areas of data structures are not appropriately covered, though. In particular with respect to databases algorithms on [trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28data_structure%29) especially [b-trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) tend to be important but are not at all covered by STL.

The STL container `std::multimap<...>` does contain a tree (typically a [red/black-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree) but that's not mandated) but it is tied to this particular in-memory representation. There is no way to apply the algorithms used to implement this particular data structure to some suitable persistent representation. Also, a `std::multimap<...>` still uses just one key (the *multi* refers to allowing multiple elements with the same key, not to having multiple keys) while database typically require multiple look-up mechanisms ([indices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index) which are utilized when executing queries based on a [query plan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_plan) for each query.

You got multiple questions and the interesting one (in my opinion) is this: "... or can I make an equally as fast (time complexity wise) homemade SQL using a c++ STL?"

In a perfect world where STL covers all algorithms, yes, you could create a query evaluator for a database based on the STL algorithms. You could even use some of the STL containers as auxiliary data structures although the primary data structures in a database are properly represented in persistent storage. To create an actual database you'd also need something which translates the query into a good query plan which can then be executed.

Of course, if all you really need are some look-ups by a key in a data structure which is read at some point by the program, you wouldn't need a full-blown database and looks are probably faster using suitable STL containers.

Note, that the [time complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) tends to be useful for guiding a quick evaluations of different approaches. However, in practice the constant factors tend to matter and often the algorithms with the inferior time complexity behaves better. The canonical example is [quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) which outperforms the "superior" algorithms (e.g. [heapsort](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort) or [mergesort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort)) for typical inputs (although in practice actually [introsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort) is used which is a hybrid of quicksort, heapsort, and [insertion-sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) is used which combines the strength of these respective algorithms to behave well on all inputs). BTW, to get an illustration of the algorithms you may want to watch the [Hungarian Sort Dancers](https://www.youtube.com/user/AlgoRythmics).

Comment: Great answer with a spectacular set of _relevant_ links

Comment: Did he answer whether sql was faster than std map???